Is spin relaxation asymmetric in magnetic semiconductors?
I am considering photo-excitation in magnetic semiconductors (e.g. metal organic frameworks). The cartoon picture is like this:

where there will be a spin polarization in the conduction band since the valence band is spin polarized. My question is in regards to spin relaxation of those photo-excited spins. Since the conduction band is split, will there be preferential spin relaxation into the down spin band since it is lower in energy (i.e. fast spin flips from up to down but slow spin flips from down to up)? So, over time (ignoring recombination for now), the conduction band will end up spin down polarized?  I couldn't find anything in the literature saying this is the case but it makes sense to me.
